# Need Help resolving npm issues eresolve report

Tags: angular, npm

Im having issues with doing a simple npm install. I am using angular latest cli version.
I have re installed angular, node and npm but it does not seem to resolve these issues.

Here is my eresolve-report:

```
While resolving: fsl-angular-task@0.0.0
Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
node_modules/@angular/common
  @angular/common@"~11.2.14" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.3.7
node_modules/@angular/cdk
  @angular/cdk@"^13.3.7" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "version": "11.2.14",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "fsl-angular-task",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "path": "<cant show directory>"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/common",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@angular/common",
        "spec": "~11.2.14",
        "from": {
          "location": "<cant show directory>"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "~11.2.14",
    "from": {
      "location": "C:\\<cant show directory>"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@angular/cdk",
      "version": "13.3.7",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "fsl-angular-task",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "path": "C:\\<cant show directory>"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/cdk",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@angular/cdk",
          "spec": "^13.3.7",
          "from": {
            "location": "<cant show directory>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Is there anyway someone can help please, thanks
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `npm` and `node` version are you using? I believe that upgrading to a newer node version might solve the problem.

This error happens because you are trying to install conflicting packages:

```
@angular/common@"~11.2.14" from the root project
// and
@angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0"
```

Try adding the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag, this is not really recommended but might ignore the issue in your case.